# Severe rendering issue in some fonts - what happened?

Tags: discussion

Looks like my [latest answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33271/13662)  caused trouble for some people (see revisions for details.) I'm so sorry about that!

So the edit says that somebody removed the bolding of kanji (which was on the word 羽織) to *"correct severe rendering issue."*

I was just curious to know what / how things got all messed up - because it was rendering just fine with furigana extension turned on here w/ Safari 9.1 on Mac OS X 10.10.5. Maybe emphasizing kanji also breaks the rendering, I guess?

And yes, no more bolding kanjis. I'll be careful next time.

---

p.s. I came across [this post](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/chrome-kanji-renderings-murdering-my-eyes-how-to-fix) in which the asker claims that *kanji renderings are murdering his eyes*, Is this it?

Comment: Just found the [sandbox question](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1540/formatting-sandbox-please-test-stuff-here) on meta. I tested that out there, but it looks like it's working to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues at [Chrome Kanji renderings murdering my eyes: how to fix?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/chrome-kanji-renderings-murdering-my-eyes-how-to-fix) should already have mostly been fixed with updates to the Furigana engine: Japanese text now has `lang="ja"` [added](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1277) to make sure Japanese fonts are explicitly used since the update of September 2014.

I think that bolded (and maybe italic) Japanese (and Chinese) should generally be avoided because of the issues at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060914-02/?p=29743.

It appears there's no guarantees bolded 漢字 will render well on a given PC, and  it looks like (as far as I can tell), not much can be done about it.

Comment: Although, as might be extrapolated from the MSDN article, I guess bolding may be less of an issue for less crowded Kanji with fewer strokes than "織" or "慶"??

Comment: OK, so some kanjis have lines too crumpled in one single place that bolding them might make them look like pieces of "black thing." I haven't thought this as that big problem because I could actually "read" most of them from their outlines maybe because I was following all the context there. But yeah, I'll avoid formatting them.

Comment: @cypher I marked the question [status-completed].

Comment: I do wonder what browser/OS combo this happens on.  I tried on SeaMonkey/Win7, Chrome/Win7, Firefox/Ubuntu, Chrome/Ubuntu, and Safari/iOS, and the bold in the original post was perfectly legible on all of them.

Comment: @snailboat Barring going through the logs, we may never know I guess. It could also be someone with J fonts installed, but not corresponding Japanese/East Asian rendering support installed or something(?)